# Circle hard problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a recent test, I was given this exercise.
A point P is 25cm away from the center of a circle. Form this point two tangents were drawn to a circle AP and PB. The distance between AB is 24cm. Find the radius. Can someone explain plz?

Comment: "The distance between the two points is 24cm." The distance between which two points? Between the two points where the tangents touch the circle?

Comment: Yes the two points touching the circle

Comment: Well, then it's just a matter of applying the Pythagorean theorem. If I have calculated correctly, possible solutions are 15cm and 20cm.

Comment: @Xaver: this is hardly a hint.

Comment: On the contrary. The hint to apply the Pythagorean theorem is a very relevant.

Comment: @Xaver: the accepted solution, which is a good one, does not use it.

Comment: The author of the so-called solution uses $ab=12^2$, which is an application of the geometric mean theorem. Where I come from, the geometric mean theorem is considered to be part of the Pythagorean theorem. Besides: The accepted solution is not really a complete solution. After you calculated $a$ and $b$, IMHO you have to use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another hint**:

In a right triangle, the altitude is the geometric mean of the segments it delimits on the hypotenuse. If you denote these lengths $a$ and $b$, you obtain the standard high school problem
$$ab= 12^2,\qquad a+b=25.$$

Comment: I didn't make the calculations nor say which segment would have length $a$  and which length $b$.

Comment: you are taking "a" as the altitude over the chord, but which one is b?

Comment: The rest of the length of the hypotenuse AC (C being the centre of the circle).

Comment: I don't understand a+b=25

Comment: where does it come from?

Comment: The length AC is $25$  by your hypothesis.

Comment: no PC=25 not AC

Comment: Oh! yes, I didn't check the name of the outer point. In all my comments, replace A with P.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The blue triangle is a right triangle

[image]

Comment: yeah that's the picture

Comment: What is the problem with that. The blue triangle is a tight triangle

Comment: @ProfessorVector: I do see one, the base is a red segment and the height is the upper half of the green segment. (I hope your screen is not black & white).